# What's wrong with this Groovy expression?

Tags: groovy, syntax-error

Running the following Groovy expression through the `GroovyShell` (interpreter):

```
if(fizz.subtype == null) {
    if(fizz.color == 'RED') fizz.subtype = "DOG";
    else if(fizz.color == 'BLUE') fizz.subtype = "CAT";
    else if(fizz.color == 'GREEN') fizz.subtype = "SHEEP";
    else if(fizz.color == 'ORANGE') fizz.subtype = "LION";
    else if(fizz.color == 'YELLOW') fizz.subtype = "SNAIL";
    else if(fizz.color == 'GRAY') fizz.subtype = "SHARK";
    else if(fizz.color == 'PURPLE') fizz.subtype = "BAT";
    else if(fizz.color == 'BLACK') fizz.subtype = "FOX";
}; fizz;
```

Gives me the following stack trace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: subtype for class: com.me.myapp.Fizz
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:479)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:543)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at com.tms.evaluator.GroovyEvaluator._evaluate(GroovyEvaluator.java:51)
    ...rest of stacktrace omitted for brevity
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure, if this is possible : fizz.color == 'RED'. Because single quotes are used only for CHAR expression as far as I know... Did you try fizz.color == "RED"?

Comment: @libik In Groovy you can do wonders, just try Groovy someday, you will never go back. ;) BTW, you can have strings with single quotes in Groovy.

Comment: How does `Fizz`  class look like?

Comment: @dmahapatro - the `Fizz` class contains a String field called `subtype`

Comment: If [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6231514/) is what you have then you should not have any issue. Will has mentioned the same considering `fizz` as a map.

Comment: which version of Groovy are you using? how do you initialize the fizz variable? please share the source of the Fizz class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the closing bracket of the `if` expression:

```
fizz = [:]
if(fizz.subtype == null) {
    if(fizz.color == 'RED') fizz.subtype = "DOG";
    else if(fizz.color == 'BLUE') fizz.subtype = "CAT";
    else if(fizz.color == 'GREEN') fizz.subtype = "SHEEP";
    else if(fizz.color == 'ORANGE') fizz.subtype = "LION";
    else if(fizz.color == 'YELLOW') fizz.subtype = "SNAIL";
    else if(fizz.color == 'GRAY') fizz.subtype = "SHARK";
    else if(fizz.color == 'PURPLE') fizz.subtype = "BAT";
    else if(fizz.color == 'BLACK') fizz.subtype = "FOX";
}; fizz;
```

Also, may i suggest using a map for this kind of data matching?

```
fizz.color = 'ORANGE'

fizz.subtype = [
    'RED'    : 'DOG',
    'BLUE'   : "CAT",
    'GREEN'  : "SHEEP",
    'ORANGE' : "LION",
    'YELLOW' : "SNAIL",
    'GRAY'   : "SHARK",
    'PURPLE' : "BAT",
    'BLACK'  : "FOX"
][fizz.color]

assert fizz.subtype == 'LION'
```

A [case-match](https://github.com/will-lp/graphology-case-match/) could also work, but it would be best suited if you had a more complex task:

```
fizz.color = 'BLUE'

fizz.subtype = fizz.color.case {
    when 'RED'    then 'DOG'
    when 'BLUE'   then "CAT"
    when 'GREEN'  then "SHEEP"
    when 'ORANGE' then "LION"
    when 'YELLOW' then "SNAIL"
    when 'GRAY'   then "SHARK"
    when 'PURPLE' then "BAT"
    when 'BLACK'  then "FOX"
}

assert fizz.subtype == 'CAT'
```

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) - I added a semi-colon to the outer `if` statement as you suggested, but now its giving me an entirely different error (please see my edits). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @WillP Nice! Not seen your case-match before :-) I've done something similar https://gist.github.com/timyates/3002724 off to investigate yours now :-D

Comment: Cool, @Tim! And very simple, also. Found the `when {} {}` syntax great!